# Check installed products in WIX

Tags: wix

How to check installed products using WIX?If they are not installed, install

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading about [AppSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367578(VS.85).aspx) action (and WiX [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) and [FileSearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_filesearch.htm) elements) and [Bootstrapper](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/Bootstrapper) concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Upgrade table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372379(VS.85).aspx) to detect other MSI products. Not necessarily intuitive but can work very well.